# SSRS Subreports's Subreport is not rendering main report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a Main report A, and many subreports in it. In the parent Subreport (Let say B) there is again a child subreport (Let say C) in it. When I combine all the subreports and run the main report, My subreport throws an Error saying (Subreport cannot be shown). But the twist here is I am having 6 subreports under the main report in which subreport 1, 2 and 3 has child subreports in it and only the subreport that is placed first in the layout of the main report displays its corresponding child subreport renders in the main report whereas the rest of the subreports doesn't.

Please help with some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that your report chain doesn't provide the required parameter(s) to your child reports, and the child report parameter(s) don't have default values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In that case, it should error out for all the subreports in my main report. But it renders the subreport that i keep first in order. i chnged the order to test this and whatever subreport i keep first it renders it and the rest subreports errors out